# Как создать оповещения личных сообщений Авито, JavaScript возможен?

Tags: javascript, парсер, puppeteer, crm

Хочу написать парсер для Авито и доставать из личного профиля количество непрочитанных сообщений. Но Puppetteer, открывая мой профиль, не может ввести имя и пароль потому что я не могу указать ему поле для ввода через ID.
При запуске данного кода вылезает ваш модальное окно у которого нет ID. Как решить данную проблему без ID или найти его ?

```
//console.log("Hello world")

const puppeteer = require(`puppeteer`);

(async () =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.avito.ru/profile/messenger`)
    
   // await page.screenshot({path: `img.png`})
const targetInput = '#value';//id нужного инпута  
 await page.waitForSelector(targetInput);  
 await page.type(targetInput,"ваши данные");  
 const submitButton = '#submit';//id кнопки
подтверждения  
 await page.waitForSelector(submitButton);   
await page.click(submitButton);

   let arr = await page.evaluate (() => {
       let text = document.querySelector(`h3`).innerText
       return text

   })

console.log(arr)
    // await browser.close() })()
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: почему, в качестве способа решения задачи, вы выбрали скрапинг, а не использование api авито?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под NPM? Первая версия вопроса была лучше, надо было просто код добавлять как код, а не картинку. Сейчас непонятно в чем именно проблема заключается

Comment: Я совсем не знаком с api авито. Насколько я понял это услуга по интеграции с уже существующими CRM.

Comment: Под NPM я имел ввиду что кроме ванильного JavaScript я своими руками могу присоединить какую нибудь библиотеку из node.js (наподобие той же puppeteer) . Правда я не уверен что это самый лучший вариант. Просто через него у меня хоть что то получается доставать из сайтов.

Comment: api - это возможность запрашивать данные напрямую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector) принимает [css селектор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), а не только `id`.

Выбрать нужные инпуты можно [по атрибуту](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) `data-marker`.

Для логина его значение будет `[data-marker="login-form/login/input"]`
Для остальных кнопок и полей ввода - аналогично.

Comment: Спасибо помогло. :)

Comment: Также помогло для остальных кнопок. Спасибо, проблема решена.